# Why when adding new tag to gameobject i'm getting exception Tag: B is not defined?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        generatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);

            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            //Generate random x,y,z scale on the terrain
            randScaleX = Random.Range(3, 70);
            randScaleY = Random.Range(70, 170);
            randScaleZ = Random.Range(50, 270);

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            //Generate the Prefab on the generated position        
            objInstance = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);
            if (randomScale == true)
                objInstance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            if (name != "")
                objInstance.name = name;

            if (tagName != "")
                objInstance.tag = tagName;

            if (parent)
                objInstance.transform.parent = this.transform;

            generatedObjects.Add(objInstance);
        }
    }
```

The exception is on the line

```
objInstance.tag = tagName;
```

tagName is a global string variable set in the top to ""
I'm trying to add a tag to each GameObject but getting this B exception.
Tried also objInstance.transform.tag but same exception.

Comment: Are you sure `tagName` is a possible tag in the tags list of the Unity Editor (at edit time) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a tag to a GameObject if you didn't define it first in the Unity Editor for your project. Go in the Inspector, and select "Tag". You will then get an option "Add Tag..." that you can use to add the desired tag name. As the tag you want to add to your GameObject will be defined, you won't get this error anymore. Make sure that the name of the tag you want to add correspond to an existing name in your tag list.

[image]

To know more about tags and how to use them, you can also check Unity's [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) on the matter.